# Passing argument with goog.events.listen

Tags: javascript, events, click, google-closure, google-closure-library

I'm using Google Closure's event handling like this:

```
goog.events.listen(this.contentElement, goog.events.EventType.CLICK, this.openEditor);
```

But I need to pass a string as an argument into the function which would be `this.openeditor`

I've looked through the documentation but can't seem to work out how to do this, anyone got any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to fire the event, or are you trying to make it so that when the event is fired, `this.openEditor` will be passed a certain string?

Comment: The latter. The function will be called whilst passing the String.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using [goog.partial](https://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/namespace_goog.html#goog.partial), like this:

```
goog.events.listen(this.contentElement, goog.events.EventType.CLICK, goog.partial(this.openEditor,'the string you want to pass it'));
```

When `this.contentElement` is clicked, `this.openEditor` will be called. The fist parameter will be the string and the second parameter will be an event object.

Comment: In many cases like this you'll want to use `goog.bind` so your current `this` is set as the context when the function is called. You can also pass `this` to goog.events.EventHandler and listen on that.

Answer (score 2):

Above answer from Joshua is right - just want to add some more info to it.

**goog.bind vs goog.partial**  defined in base.js

In goog.partial the context is set to current context - it returns a function which gets executed in current context.

```
goog.partial = function(fn, var_args) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return function() {
    // Clone the array (with slice()) and append additional arguments
    // to the existing arguments.
    var newArgs = args.slice();
    newArgs.push.apply(newArgs, arguments);
    return fn.apply(this, newArgs);
  };
};
```

Where as in goog.bind ( which actually checks for native implementation of bind) and  you can pass the context as second parameter

```
goog.bind = function(fn, selfObj, var_args) {
  //defined in base.js  
  ....
  ....
  return function() {
    return fn.apply(selfObj, arguments);
  };

}
```